# New SSD installing 16.10 : BootDevice Not Found

Tags: boot, ssd, 16.10

Just installed Ubuntu 16.10 on the new SSD (which worked, no problems during installation). I recieve the following error:

```
BootDevice Not Found
Please install an operating system on your hard disk.
Hard Disk - (3F0)
```

I tried to search AskUbuntu. Some options I have tried:

- Refitting the SSD
- Selecting Legacy and/or Uefi within the Bios
- Changed the boot options in the bios
- Factory reset of Bios
- Checked with Live Ubuntu on USB stick if the installation files where on the HDD.
- Preformed HP System diagnostic harddisk test and it succeeded
- Did run Boot-Repair on default mode

I am using a Kingston SSD and a HP ProBook 6560b.

Comment: That depends on 1. How you installed (UEFI or Legacy) and 2. Selecting the correct boot device.

Comment: That sounds like a UEFI or BIOS error. If Secure boot is on, then it is because your install is not in Secure boot mode. But if an HP, if only is pre-configured to boot Windows using UEFI description. If only booting Ubuntu change description of UEFI entry from ubuntu to "Windows Boot Manager". That as # IV and other work arounds:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @CelticWarrior I did not install UEFI or Legacy as far as I know. This is what I mean with selecting the correct boot [device](https://flic.kr/p/NkvqGS).

Comment: @oldfred The option provided at #IV return the follwoing _EFI variabled are not supported on this system_

Comment: Did you boot in UEFI mode. efibootmgr only works with UEFI, not with BIOS.

Comment: Ok I will enable the UEFI in the Bios and then try it again. Thanks for support.

Comment: Hmm I think I do not understand it correctly. I have selectid UEFI mode within the Bios. Restarted the OS, ran the Ubuntu Live and filled it the sudo efibootmgr -c -L "Windows Boot Manager" -l "\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi". But this still returns _EFI variabled are not supported on this system_. If I read it correctly the UFI should be a partition with some software on it. This partition is currently not present on my system.

Comment: This is a [screenshot](https://flic.kr/p/NdAsLE) after a installation. I tried it using DVD with 16.04 installed on it to see if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@All, after reading some on the internet I decided to install an bios update. So I swapped back an old HDD containing windows. Installed the bios update using an HP tool found online. Swapped the HDD with the SSD. Made sure UFI boot was set up. On the new SSD I created an [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Creating_an_UEFI_partition) partition using Ubuntu live. Reboot and installed Ubuntu. It is working now. Thanks for the help!